# how to delete image in nodejs express through filename

Tags: node.js, image, express

I am trying to delete the image if it already exists but on the console it says path not found.. I tried debugging copied the path and pasted on the windows explorer and i got the image sucessfully. While nodejs express says that file not found.

```
if (profile_pic) {
        if (profile_pic != "") {
          const old_profile_pic = userDataForGender[0].profile_pic;
          if (old_profile_pic != "") {
            const full_path =
              appDir + `/uploads/profile-pics/${old_profile_pic}`;
            fs.stat(full_path, function (err, stats) {
              if (err) {
                console.error("error on line 128" + err);
              } else {
                fs.unlink(full_path, async function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log("error on line 132" + err);
                  } else {
                    filename =
                      (await generateRandomString()) + "_" + "profile_pic.jpg";
                      updatedData["profile_pic"] = filename;
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          } else {
            filename = (await generateRandomString()) + "_" + "profile_pic.jpg";
            updatedData["profile_pic"] = filename;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: It seems you need to do add `console.log(full_path)` and see exactly what your constructed path is.  Likely an error in constructing the full path.

Answer (score -1):

change "/uploads/profile-pics" to "uploads/profile-pics"
fs.unlinkSync("uploads/profile-pics" + "abcd.jpg")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).